# passing arguments to a new-object inside a start-job

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore the database on two sql servers at the same time. That is why I need to have the `restore-sqldatabase` run as a job in the background, this way I will be able to run the second restore job at the same time.

The `receive-job` shows 4 errors `cannot index into a null array`, passing variables from an argument list into the script block is fine, but passing variables into the script block into the new-object command "which takes its own argument list" seems to be the problem.

Similar questions are not very identical to what I want to accomplish. Any help is really appreciated.

```
Start-Job -InitializationScript { 
#load assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
#Need SmoExtended for backup
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
} -Name JobP -ScriptBlock {
$serverConn = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $($args[0])
$serverConn.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0


$RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("$($args[1])", "$($arg[2])")
$RelocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("$($args[3])", "$($arg[4])")

Restore-SqlDatabase -InputObject $serverConn -Database $($args[5]) -BackupFile "$($args[6])" -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog) -ReplaceDatabase
} -ArgumentList $ServerPrimary,$database_logical_name,$database_path,$log_logical_name,$log_path,$database,$backupfile_full_path
```

Comment: reading other posts, they suggest passing the argument list to param inside the script block. I will try that, if it works I'll post the new updated script. the syntax suggested is as follows -scriptblock{ param($p1,$p2) ........}

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank stackoverflow and all the previous threads that dealt with passing variables to to a script block through param($p1, $p2)

I managed to solve the problem with trial and error, right now the script is working. here is the solution:

```
    Start-Job -InitializationScript {
    #load assemblies [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
    #Need SmoExtended for backup
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended")  | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
} -Name JobP -ScriptBlock {

#Define the parameters to be used inside the script block, $p0 will be the first arguments in the "-ArgumentList", $p1 will be the second and so on. 
param($p0, $p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6)
$serverConn = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $p0
$serverConn.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0

#the below variables are necessary incase you have your data and log in a different  location than the default.
$RelocateData = New-Object  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("$p1", "$p2")
$RelocateLog = New-Object   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("$p3", "$p4")

echo $p0 $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4 $p5 $p6

Restore-SqlDatabase -InputObject $serverConn -Database "$p5" -BackupFile "$p6" -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog) -ReplaceDatabase
} -ArgumentList $ServerPrimary,$database_logical_name,$database_path,$log_logical_name,$log_path,$database,$backupfile_full_path
```